Can this differential equation be solved exactly? $\frac{d y(x+x_0)}{dx}+P(x)y(x)+Q(x)y(x+x_1)=f(x)$
Can the following differential equation be solved exactly? Note that there is a non--vanishing displacement in the function $y$
$\frac{d y(x+x_0)}{dx}+P(x)y(x)+Q(x)y(x+x_1)=f(x)$

Update:
Let's assume $y$ has a Taylor expansion.
We then arrive at
$$
\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(x,x_0,x_1)y^{(n)}(x)=f(x)
$$
Define $\Psi=[y(x),y'(x),y''(x),\cdots]^T$ and we can rewrite the equation into
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\Psi+M(x,x_0,x_1)\Psi=\begin{bmatrix}f(x)\\0\\ \vdots\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $M(x,x_0,x_1)$ is a infinite-dimensional matrix. Now the problem is how to construct this $M$ so that it is invertible?

You have a linear delay differential operator.

The Buchstab function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchstab_function) is the solution to a much simpler differential delay equation, and it can't be solved exactly, so I wouldn't hold out much hope for an exact solution to your equation.

@YvesDaoust Yes, $y'+py=q$ can be solved exactly, where $y=$exp(-\int p dx)\int q exp(\int p dx) dx$.

I call a solution is an exact solution or analytical solution if it can be written in a form that $y=F(P,Q,x)$ where there is no $y$ on the right--hand side.

I would be very surprised if an exact solution could be produced for general $f(x)$. However, if you just want to get an exact solution for particular choices of the coefficients, it is quite easy: Just choose $y(x), P(x), Q(x), x_0, x_1$ and compute $f(x)$ by plugging everything else in the equation. This way, by construction, the selected $y(x)$ is a solution of the delay equation for those particular $x_0, x_1, P(x), Q(x)$ and $f(x)$. This is sometimes referred to as the "method of manufactured solutions", quite useful in the benchmark of numerical methods.
For instance, the constant function $y \equiv 1$will be a solution to the delay equation if you choose the coefficients in a way that $f(x)=P(x)+Q(x)$.

Can you solve it when $f(x)=0$?

No, not for general $P(x), Q(x)$. I'm not saying it is impossible, just that I have no idea how to do it.
